# <BEA-000403> <IOException occurred on socket: Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=55554,localport=7001]

Tags: sockets, intellij-idea, jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic12c

Anyone have a clue about this exception I got when starting Weblogic 12 :

```
<25 sept. 2019 09 h 28 GMT> <Error> <Socket> <BEA-000403> <IOException occurred on socket: Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=55554,localport=7001]
 java.io.IOException: Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte.
java.io.IOException: Une connexion établie a été abandonnée par un logiciel de votre ordinateur hôte.
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:197)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:379)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>
```

I didn't find any similar issue!

Thanks

Comment: Seems you need patch 18373180 for non-english systems: http://admintomv.blogspot.com/2014/12/weblogic-installation-on-non-english.html

Comment: @y.bedrov Yeah but where can we find this patch?

Comment: I don't have Oracle account, but seems link is mentioned here: https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/community/middleware/3774134.html

Comment: Here's the problem! I don't know how to get the content of this page. I don't either have an oracle account for that

Comment: You may register to get Oracle account and then try to download patch

Comment: I've solved this problem by integrating a needed certifications into JDK.
I knew it by activating audit logs in weblogic and visualize the exact issue :)